# i've got a problem with flask using app.route()

Tags: python, flask

i'm trying to create a web server with Flask python library but there is something wrong because it keeps giving me the error when i run the file.

here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, app

app = Flask(__name__)

@app_route("/")
def main():
    return('welcome to my flask page')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port="8090")
```

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Simone\Simone\Js Course\Python Web Server\web server.py", line 5, in <module>
    @app_route("/")
NameError: name 'app_route' is not defined
```

Help me please!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `app` you're importing from flask isn't what you expect (it's a module within `Flask` that contains flask code). You need to create an instance of `Flask`, and apply the route to that.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__file__)   # add this

@app.route('/')  # and use app.route instead of app_route
...
```